# Does GNU cpp interpret the C99 standard oddly for macros of zero arguments?

Tags: c, macros, gnu, c99, c-preprocessor

Why does GNU cpp accept the following code, even when run with the flags -std=c99 -pedantic:

```
#define z()
#define w(x)
z()
w()
w(1)
```

The C99 Standard requires that the number of arguments in a function-like macro invocation shall match the number of parameters in the macro definition (and is happy with the idea that an argument may consist of an empty sequence of preprocessing tokens so presumably the first two invocations provide a single empty argument), but this cannot be true for all three invocations.

Indeed surely z must be only be invoked with zero arguments, which is syntactically impossible?

Comment: Note that a 2 argument macro provides errors in gcc when used without arguments.

Comment: Empty arguments are only relevant when the macro takes arguments.  `z` takes no arguments, so the parentheses must be empty.  All else apart, backwards compatibility dictates that the `z()` invocation must continue to work.  The special case here is `w()`; since `w` takes an argument but there are no characters for it, the argument is treated as empty.

Answer (score 2):

A few experiments show that the first `w` line is interpreted as one empty argument:

```
#define w(x) #x
w()
w(1)
```

when preprocessed gives:

```
""
"1"
```

Even better:

```
#define w(x, y) #x <-> #y
w(,)
w(1,)
w(, 2)
w(1, 2)
```

gives:

```
"" <-> ""
"1" <-> ""
"" <-> "2"
"1" <-> "2"
```

Nifty...

Dunno what the standard says about this. Must ask a lawyer...

Comment: That seems to be what the standard says should happen.  The argument can be empty (as in `w()`) or `1` (as in `w(1)`), but then `z()` should be an error.

Comment: @user3348948, my compiler(s) say that the macro `z` has to take exactly *zero* arguments. That makes sense, specially with respect to functions without arguments. But I don't even play a language lawyer on TV, much less here...

Comment: That's also what the standard says.  The number of parameters in the definition of z is clearly zero, so if `z()` is OK then I wonder why `w()` is too since that clearly wants exactly one argument?

Answer (score 1):

Macro usage is different from function invocation in one important aspect: macro arguments may be empty. This is valid:

```
#define x(a,b)  X a X b X
x(,)  //-> X X X
x(1,) //-> X 1 X X
x(,2) //-> X X 2 X
```

Given that empty arguments are allowed, this macro usage:

```
#define x(a) X a X
x()  //-> X X
```

must be interpreted as an empty argument. While this one:

```
#define x() XX
x()  //-> XX
```

is a macro without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The only language in the standard that I can use to work with this is as follows:

> **C 2011. Section 6.10.3 Macro Replacement. Part of Paragraph 10:**
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form:
>
> ```
> # define identifier lparen identifier-list_opt ) replacement-list new-line
> # define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
> # define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
> ```
>
> defines a function-like macro with parameters, whose use is
>   similar syntactically to a function call.

That being said, the standard does give examples of valid macro replacements. They include:

```
#define p() int
#define t(a) a
#define glue(a, b) a ## b

p()       // Produces: int
t(x)      // Produces: x
glue(1,2) // Produces: 12
```

Comment: They are also in the C99 standard. So perhaps `p()` has _zero_ arguments, though the earlier part of 6.10.3 says "If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments (including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens) [..]" which suggests otherwise.

Comment: @user3348948, the `_opt` tells you that parameterless macros are allowed. And the `(including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens)` wording explicitly says there can be empty arguments. Strictly legal, AFAICS. But IANAL. Nice to know. Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntactic ambiguity here.  Given a function-like macro invocation `x()`, the empty sequence of tokens between the parentheses can be interpreted as no arguments, or as one empty argument.  GCC resolves the ambiguity by looking at the macro definition:

```c
#define x()  replacement
#define y(a) repl##a##cement

x() y()
```

will preprocess without error to

```c
replacement replcement
```

I no longer have C99 section 6.10 memorized to the point where I can say off the top of my head why this is the correct behavior, but I'm certain that it is, because if it wasn't I would have made GCC do something else. ;-)

There is some discussion of these rules, in relatively informal terms, at the bottom of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html .  Note in particular that given

```c
#define z(a,b) stuff with a and b
```

it *is* an error to write `z()`, but `z(,)` is acceptable.